# Is the "What's With Andy" song "Kindergarten Blues" based on a real classic blues song?

Tags: blues

I remember seeing this episode when I was growing up and after some searching I found it on youtube. Is this song based on a classic one?

Comment: All blues songs sound very much like all other blues songs. Blues is the simplest form and structure found in popular music of the 20th and 21st centuries. It's the same today as it was in the year 1912. You might as well say that *every* blues song is based on a classic blues song.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a single song that this is modelled on - it's a standard [12-bar blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-bar_blues) (along the lines of [Sweet Home Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_Home_Chicago), but there are many others that follow that pattern) that incorporates other well-known elements like the shuffle rhythm, and the riff/figure from [I'm a Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_a_Man_(Bo_Diddley_song)) / [Mannish Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannish_Boy).

Possibly, the use of such 'standard', clichéd elements is part of the humour.